# Sorry, there's been a disconnect Power Platform will start relying on a new cloud service dependency called Power Platform API

Tags: azure, powerapps, administration, powerapps-formula, power-platform

I am trying to create a trial Power Apps account. I have created admin profile at admin center and checked power apps license.

While trying to go to make.powerapps.com, I am facing this error:

> Power Platform will start relying on a new cloud service dependency called Power Platform API, evaluate adding the service to your Conditional Access policies, and updated URLs to your firewall rules.

I have added Power Apps in Azure Conditional Access policy, however I cant access Azure Firewall this Microsoft admin account.

Any help to bypass this error would be great!